# How to get json data from web api paging listview paging syncfusion for xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

i want to get data from database through webapi and show in listview, but with lsitview i want to use paging. I am using syncfusion for listview paging. I have done some part but i am getting error

the error i am getting is 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

```
private List<products> products = new List<products>();
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://orangepotato.rjcpacking.com/index.php?route=api/login/getFeaturedProducts");
protected async void FeaturedList()
        { products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<products>>(json);
 dataPager.Source = products;
}
void Handle_OnDemandLoading(object sender, Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.DataPager.OnDemandLoadingEventArgs e)
        {
            var source= products.Skip(e.StartIndex).Take(e.PageSize);
            FeaturedlistView.ItemsSource = source.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

the json returned by the service is an object containing a list.  You cannot deserialize it directly into a List

using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com), I get this model for the json

```
public class Product
{
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string thumb { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string special { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public string discount_percentage { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```